# Discord.py | I have a problem with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a basic **Error Handler** but it seems that everytime I ping someone or I use an emoji then one of the Error Handlers gets activated. This one: `commands.CommandNotFound`. So I thought it could be because it a tag and an emoji starts with `@` and with `:` so the bot could get confused and think that these 2 were prefixes. So I tried to make an If statement that everytime that everytime it has to see if the message starts with the prefix of the bot. But it seems I'm pretty dumb and new in discord.py so I got an error in the problems sections. Could someone explain to me how to make an If statement with `message.startsWith` or anything that would be helpful?

My code(Insade a cog):

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

class Errors(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if ctx.message.startsWith(f'{client.prefix}'):
        

            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                errorrequired = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description='', color=0xf76300)
                errorrequired.add_field(name='Error: Missing An Argument', value='You are using the command wrong, make sure to add every argument!.\nContact <@434843854030635009> if you think this is a bug!')
                errorrequired.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                errorrequired.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.channel.send(embed=errorrequired)
        
            elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
                errorargument = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description='', color=0xf76300)
                errorargument.add_field(name='Error: User Not Found', value='Could not find the user you are looking for.\nContact <@434843854030635009> if you think this is a bug!')
                errorargument.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                errorargument.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.channel.send(embed=errorargument)
        """
        elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            errornotfound = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description='', color=0xf76300)
            errornotfound.add_field(name='Error: Command can not be found', value='This command does not exit.\nContact <@434843854030635009> if you think this is a bug!')
            errornotfound.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            errornotfound.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.icon_url)

            await ctx.channel.send(embed=errornotfound)
        elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            errorperms = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description='', color=0xf76300)
            errorperms.add_field(name='Error: Missing Permissions', value='You are missing a required permission to run this command.\nContact <@434843854030635009> if you think this is a bug!')
            errorperms.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            errorperms.set_author(name=f'{ctx.author}', icon_url=ctx.author.icon_url)

            await ctx.channel.send(embed=errorperms)
        """
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Errors(client))
```

Also the problem/Error I get:

```
Undefined variable 'client'
```

Note: the `MissingPermissions` and `CommandNotFound`  are inside a comment just to be sure that the bot will not start sending embeds for every ping that happens.

Comment: So much repetition of code.  You should know what DRY means.  I'd recommend refactoring that code into a common method and passing in what changes for each instance.  Less code means fewer bugs.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right, but t here is no fun in that tho. Also fixing bugs is important too. If this does get fixed I could be able to help others in the same way that's why I'm not doing that. If it was about that I would just go and copy someone's else **Error Handler**.

Comment: `ctx.message` it's a `discord.Message` instance, so it doesn't have the `startswith` method, you should use `ctx.message.content.startswith`, also that if statement is useless, if the messsage starts with any other prefix no errors will be called

Comment: DRY is key.  You make a mistake by ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `client` object is `self.client`, not `client`, that's why you have this undefined variable error.
Also, [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot) objects don't have any `prefix` attribute. To get your bot's prefixes, you can use [`Bot.get_prefix(message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_prefix):

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    prefixes = await self.client.get_prefix(ctx.message)
    if ctx.message.content[0] in prefixes:
        ...
```

I also noticed two other erros:

- The method you use the "starts with" method id `startswith()` not `startsWith()`
- `ctx.message` will return a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object, not a string so you'd need to write `ctx.message.content` instead.

Comment: Sorry for this late response and also thank you for the help. It seems you were right, the error handler works fine now!